# Getting error: AttributeError: class <CLASS NAME> has no attribute '<METHOD NAME>'

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
 1 #!/usr/bin/env python
  2 
  3 import re, os, sys, jira, subprocess
  4 
  5 class Check_jira:
  6 
  7     def verify_commit_text(self, tags):
  8         for line in tags:
  9             if re.match('^NO-TIK',line):
 10                 return True
 11             elif re.match('^NO-REVIEW', line):
 12                 return True
 13             elif re.match(r'[a-zA-Z]+-\d+', line):
 14                 # Validate the JIRA ID
 15                 m = re.search("([a-zA-Z]+-\d+)",line)
 16                 if m:
 17                     my_args = m.group(1)
 18                     result = Check_jira.CheckForJiraIssueRecord(my_args)
 19                     if result == False:
 20                         util.warn("%s does not exist"%my_args)
 21                     else:
 22                         return True
 23                 return True
 24             else:
 25                 return False
 26 if __name__ == '__main__':
 27     p = Check_jira()
 28     commit_text_verified = p.verify_commit_text(os.popen('hg tip --template "{desc}"'))
 29 
 30     if (commit_text_verified):
 31         sys.exit(0)
 32     else:
 33         print >> sys.stderr, ('[obey the rules!]')
 34         sys.exit(1);
 35     def CheckForJiraIssueRecord(object):
 36    
 37         sys.stdout = os.devnull
 38         sys.stderr = os.devnull
 39 
 40    
 41         try:
 42             com = jira.Commands()
 43             logger = jira.setupLogging()
 44             jira_env = {'home':os.environ['HOME']}
 45             command_cat= "cat"
 46             command_logout= "logout"
 47             #my_args = ["QA-656"]
 48             server = "http://jira.myserver.com:8080/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl"
 49         except Exception, e:
 50             sys.exit('config error')
 51 
 52 class Options:
 53     pass
 54 options = Options()
 55 
 56 options.user = 'user'
 57 options.password = 'password'
 58 
 59 try:
 60 
 61     jira.soap = jira.Client(server)
 62     jira.start_login(options, jira_env, command_cat, com, logger)
 63     issue = com.run(command_cat, logger, jira_env, my_args)
 64 except Exception, e:
 65     print sys.exit('data error')
```

so maybe:
1. if **name** == '**main**': shoudl be at the bottom ? 
2. So, i have 2 classes (Check_jira) and (Options)
3. Check_jira has 2 functions verify_commit_text() and CheckForJiraIssueRecord()
4. I pass object as an argument to CheckForJiraIssueRecord since i am passing my_args to it , on its usage.
5. Not sure how to call one function from another function in the same class
6. Error i am getting is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qa/hook-test/.hg/check_jira.py", line 31, in 
    commit_text_verified = p.verify_commit_text(os.popen('hg tip --template "{desc}"'))
  File "/home/qa/hook-test/.hg/check_jira.py", line 21, in verify_commit_text
    result = Check_jira.CheckForJiraIssueRecord(my_args)
AttributeError: class Check_jira has no attribute 'CheckForJiraIssueRecord'
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: pretxncommit.jira hook exited with status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class Check_jira` ends on line 25 and has only one method. Then you have an `if` block, and `CheckForJiraIssueRecord` is just a function defined in this block (that is, the function is defined `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

Just put the `if` block outside after the whole class definition.